# UDP RTP Stream blocked from java app

Tags: java, sockets, udp, vlc, vlcj

Hi I am making an app that streams video from android to pc. I have the streams setup correctly and am able to open the .sdp file containing my RTP stream information in VLC on any pc fine. I can get the video and audio stream and it works great.

I am also writing a java app for PC that will be able to view this stream using vlcj and do other operations between it and the android app. My problem is that this app for some reason is only functioning correctly on my pc in my college dorm room. The pcs in my computer science lab and at home over my home network give me "Destination Unreachable (Port Unreachable)" errors when viewing the traffic in wireshark. Keep in mind this only happens through my vlcj implementation, it works perfectly using the actual vlc client. It also works fine on my home pc, which should have the same setup as the one in my dorm..

I have the following callback in my code for the MediaPlayer of vlcj:

```
@Override
public void buffering(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, float newCache) {
    System.out.println("Buffering " + newCache);
}
```

In the working computer it prints 0.0, and then continues up to 100 where the video appears and plays. On the computers where it doesn't work it just says 0.0 and then stops...

I really cannot understand this issue since it uses the same dlls as the vlc client and the packets get through when using the normal vlc client. Could the jre I'm using be denying udp packets?

Well I just got another computer to work with it... the only thing I can think of that would be different in the working computers is that they have actual video cards whereas the nonworking ones have integrated cards... But I don't think that would make a difference.

Comment: If there's a firewall that prevents the source stream to reach your PC (at cs lab), you might see such an issue. If VLC client is running fine, it could be due to its support for NAT (Network address translation, I'm not sure on this) you should be able to verify it.

Comment: netstat -nap | grep <your port> should verify that your destination port is not listening. I've not used the client, but, look at the API you are using to open the socket. Verify the address and port you are feeding to the aPI and print the error/debug msgs.

Comment: netstat -nap gives me no output at all. The address I'm using is 192.168.1.9 my laptops address and the ports are 5004 and 5006. netstat -na shows 5004 open but not 5006. When I use the normal VLC windows client it shows 5004 and 5006 both open. The API I use is just a wrapper on the libraries behind the windows client and should do the same thing.  Would NAT matter on a local network? Sorry I don't know much about it. There's honestly no errors messages I can find other than ICMP message Destination Unreachable type 3 which means Port Unreachable in Wireshark.

Comment: What is the MRL you are trying to play, and how exactly are you playing it, can you post some code? vlcj and Java are not involved *at all* in the network aspect of this problem, it's all done natively in VLC - i.e. the JVM is not blocking your UDP packets.

Comment: I have a tcp connection with my android device which I use to get the .sdp file and save it at "C:\\Users\\tjhel_000\\Documents\\GitHub\\GoogleGlassWhite\\GlassStreamClient\\rtpsession.sdp" as a constant (for now). This part works fine and I get a correct .sdp file: http://pastebin.com/iVvknRwn I then just push this as an instance variable in my MediaController class and call playMedia(above mrl). I then get the "opening" event fired, followed by "Buffering 0.0", followed by "playing" event from your MediaPlayerEventAdapter. It seems very odd because as I said VLC will play from the same file

Comment: I just checked and I'm using vlcj-3.0.1 and the jna-3.5.2.jar that came packaged with it but I just read the readme and it says jna > 4.0 is required. Would that mess things up?

Comment: JNA should be irrelevant. Probably you need to play subitems. I think "playing" the SDP file creates subitems.

Comment: I have setPlaySubItems(true) called on my EmbeddedMediaPlayer :( I also have the callback for mediaSubItemAdded and it is never fired.  I tried to enable vlcj logging by using System.setProperty("Dvlcj.log", "DEBUG") but I don't know where this log file would be stored. VLC logging gives me a huge list of things that took place to get the rtp session playing.

Comment: @caprica I just noticed in vlc that if I go to open file, .sdp is listed as a playlist file. But using a MediaListPlayer doesn't work either. Do you know what would be the difference in vlc of playing a playlist as opposed to a normal media file? I looked into the difference between media_new_location and media_new_path and noticed my .sdp mrl is registered as a path which seems like it would be correct.. I'm going insane trying to figure this out

Comment: System.setProperty("vlcj.log", "DEBUG"), or "java -Dvlcj.log=DEBUG ..."